# How do you recursively sort a deeply nested array of objects and return the result - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dictionary, object

I'm **recursively** sorting a **deeply nested array of objects** by a **deeply nested obj** that is **keyed by id**.

This function works **but** when I `console.log` while invoking the function the result is `undefined`.

The unsorted array of objects passed as an argument **does get sorted** if I `console.log` it before and after the call to this function, but that is not being returned from the function call - **it is a mutation**, which I'm looking to avoid.

A couple of things I've tried:

1. Instead of the initial call to `.map()`, using `.reduce()`, and
   adding an empty array as the accumulator, which allows the function
   to return but it does not sort :/
2. Returning the array I'm calling `.map()` on at the very end works -
   but this seems like a hack, and it also encloses the result in an
   array. 
       I've tried carefully placing returns in different places - but what usually results is `[undefined]`, or arrays of arrays that
   contain **undefined**

   ```
     function sortDeepNestedArray(unsortedArray, sortedObj){unsortedArray.map((obj) => {
       const children = obj.Children;
       const Id = obj.Id
       if (children && children.every(o => !o.Children)) {
         Object.keys(sortedObj).map(key => {
           if (Id === key) {
             return children.sort((a, b) => {
               a = sortedObj[key].Children[a.Id]
               b = sortedObj[key].Children[b.Id]
               return a - b
             });
           }
         });
       }

       Object.keys(sortedObj).map(key => {
         const isNotBaseCase = children &&
         children.every(o => o.Children) &&
         Id === key &&
         sortedObj[key] &&
         sortedObj[key].Children

         if (isNotBaseCase) {
           sortDeepNestedArray(children, sortedObj[key].Children);
         }
       });
     });
   }
   ```

Comment: Any chance you can post sample input and expected result?

Comment: If you’re using `.map` and not doing anything with the result, consider `.forEach` instead.

Comment: You basically want to deep-clone the structure and then sort it. To clone an array, just use `.slice()`.

Comment: @Bergi Hmmmm....I have already deep cloned so you're right I don't need to worry about mutation. What about .map() not returning tho?

Comment: @James A deeply nested object in the array is being sorted. Is .map() used for sorting like this typically? What method is idiomatic for sorting a deeply nested array of objects?

Comment: @zero_cool Yes, you shouldn't use `map` when you don't want to create another array (I first had expected that you were using `map` to do the cloning…). Just go for `for (const key of Object.keys(…))` or `for (const key in …)`

Comment: @Bergi It's not that another array is created - it's just sorted...

Comment: @zero_cool To clone it, you need to create another array... Not sure whether you want to clone and sort separately or let `sortDeepNestedArray` do both.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think there's a need to clone it after I've already deepCloned the entire array of objects before this function gets called. This function should only sort.

Comment: @zero_cool Ok, separately it is: then you don't need a `map`.